Why would sending true names in space not work?
I have human hiveminds--human populations mentally connected to form a single, collective mind. Each hivemind holds a true name which needs to be written down to maintain their mental condition and solidify their existence. The medium holding the true name must always convey the information to the universe with completeness, clarity and legibility. Therefore, whenever the medium is compromised enough to remove the readability of the name, the hivemind can detect the loss of its existential anchor and replace it when needed.
Hiveminds carve their true names on stone blocks measuring 13 m long, 11 m wide, and 13 m tall. Since hiveminds have very long names, the names normally cover the entire block. Hiveminds with a minimum of 7 billion humans use blocks with these dimensions with the dimensions doubling for every 7 billion added. After creating the blocks, hiveminds usually cover them with cloth.
When another hivemind reads the written true name, the hivemind whose true name has been discovered risks mental assimilation from the reader. For reasons, this is why hiveminds are so obsessed with hiding their true names and finding the true names of other hiveminds. If normal humans were to read a hivemind's true name, their minds break and they become a part of the hivemind.
My setting has modern day technology. Initially, I envisioned the hiveminds hiding their blocks deep within the Earth, obscure locations, or anywhere else. However, the idea of just launching the blocks into deep space and letting them drift away until they become untraceable stuck with me. Whenever the block becomes unreadable, the hiveminds would just send another block. Since doing that would clash with the world I'm going for, I have to ask:
How do I justify this not working?

Can we presume that you're excluding distance as  factor?

We are not a brainstorming site. Stop asking us to brainstorm or generate ideas for you.

"When you notice a cat in profound meditation, the reason, I tell you, is always the same: his mind is engaged in a rapt contemplation of the thought, of the thought, of the thought of his name: his ineffable effable effanineffable deep and inscrutable singular Name." (T. S. Eliot, The Naming of Cats, 1939)

@sphennings I agree with the general sentiment, but asking for science justification for a specific effect is within the WB remit. This question is borderline, I agree, but I think it makes the cut because of the specificity of the effect being requested. It is akin to “how do I get a planet with these characteristics” questions.

There are a lot of story-based reasons that would work: the hivemind is paranoid about letting the name out of its control or not knowing exactly where it is. Or it decided it was cheaper to engrave the name microscopically onto a square cm of titanium and secrete it into the center of a growing tree. And, of course, there's the ever-present, "the author didn't write it that way" reason. After all, there's nothing stopping you from avoiding rockets and there isn't a horde of people waiting to catch you in that choice. That's why this kind of Q doesn't work here, so I agree with @sphennings.

@SRM brainstorming science based justifications is still brainstorming. There are myriad ways to skin this cat that are all "based in science". The help center is clear that questions with many equally valid answers, and questions seeking for help brainstorming are not OK. There is also long established policy through Meta discussion that idea generation is not prohibited on this site

The setup you describe is effectively magic, so what is stopping you from inventing another detail that adds the desired restriction? This could be anything vaguely mechanism based - must touch earth to be effective, has a limited range, … - or even directly forbidding the stones to leave earth lest they just stop working.

@sphennings We should move further discussion to Meta if necessary, but I see this as potentially having a best answer. I'm aware of the prohibition on idea generation... I don't think that's what this is.

@SRM It's the objective metric for choosing a best answer that's missing. Dmyt hasn't asked, "I need to achieve that result from this starting point, what would get me there?" He simply asked, "Here's the starting point, what are my options?" Stack Exchange is built around a one-specific-question/one-best-answer model, which requires asking a question with the expectation of objectively picking one best answer. This Q could have been asked that way, but wasn't and stretching the rules to keep questions open just makes us another Quora or Reddit.

@SRM, Also, Sphennings isn't kidding about discussing this for years on Meta. I tried to break the stalemate myself, but it never works. The problem is that Stack Exchange hard-codes about 85% of the rules. We can claim to circumvent them in Meta, but that's an ephemeral policy that's really hard to maintain (believe me, I've tried many times and only one or two have stuck). So, them's the rules.

VTC, because you're asking us to write the most significant feature of your story.

I'd have thought that the [science-fantasy] tag might have been appropriate, plus a number of constraints that would take this out of brainstorming territory. It would seriously help the OP if they were to be seen to engage with the comments.

FYI if you "double the dimensions" you don't get double the surface area, but four times the surface area (eight times the volume). One and a half times the dimensions would give you more than enough space for twice the name length.

FWIW, this shares some similarity with the plot of Lord of the Rings - it is proposed that the One Ring simply be thrown into the sea where it will be protected by obscurity, but the ages-long timescales involved doom that plan to failure.

More pressing question: rather than launch a 13x11x13 meter block into space why not send a drone to an asteroid  with some engraving tools?

"The medium holding the true name must always convey the information to the universe with completeness, clarity and legibility" - Could just tweak this somewhat, to require connectedness between whatever part of "the universe" the stone conveys information to and members of the hivemind.  Space is mostly empty.  A stone in space has no connectedness back to its hivemind, unlike planet-bound monoliths.  Without that connectedness, the hivemind immediately perceives it as "lost" and makes a new one. Launching them into space just creates an endless cycle of replacing the stones.

Three thoughts occur:

space is not kind to unprotected objects, the rate of degradation will probably exceed that seen somewhere like an Earth bound salt mine.

stone is heavy and you're proposing to use 1859m3 blocks of it, they weight ~5,000 tonnes a pop, putting that in orbit is a serious investment. We have never had booster platform that will do that, the Saturn V holds the record for LEO capacity at a whole 141 tonnes and change. Putting it onto an open escape orbit? Forget it.

possibly most importantly while as Douglas Adams points out “Space is big. You just won't believe how vastly, hugely, mind-bogglingly big it is. I mean, you may think it's a long way down the road to the chemist's, but that's just peanuts to space.”, space travel is not particularly unpredictable with modern technology. In short anyone watching for the launch etc... will be able to track down your true name block and capture or destroy it (with no warning degradation, just rent into atoms in an instant) relatively easily if they have the capability to put one into space themselves.



@KerrAvon2055 Quite right Granite or Quartzite, which would be the most stable options, are ~2.65 tonnes per cubic metre 4926 tonnes per block. I must have stuffed up converting somewhere along the line, If I'd had it right then Dragon XL is planned to lift 5 tonnes to the moon but the current Dragon platforms will barely get 5 tonnes into orbit.

Then why not use existing space rocks? Identify some that are just passing through and send a tiny little engraving machine to it. That can be concealed (first ideas that come to mind - you can either cover it in Vantablack or retroreflectors). Or if you're worried that it will be tracked anyway, send 1000 of them to 1000 different asteroids - but just one actually writes.

@Vilx- there are a number of problems with your suggestion.  1. Lots of comets and asteroids are very loosely held together, they are not solid masses of stone suitable for engraving.  2. A drone that could reliably and perfectly engrave almost a thousand square metres of unprepared, rough rock is probably beyond today's technology.  3. Vantablack won't stop thermal detection and the exhaust makes any changes of velocity easy to track (retroreflectors make it very easy) - at short range there is no stealth in space.

@Vilx- Anything that is actually "just passing through" is moving far too fast for us to catch it with modern detection and propulsion technology.

@KerrAvon2055 - (1) I concede. (2) I think could be plausibly made. As for (3) - my idea was to launch the little thing stealthily. That is, there's a regular rocket routinely putting things into orbit, but silently it ejects the little thing into the direction of the asteroid. All the ejection force comes from the rocket, so the little thing stays stone cold until it's already a fair distance away. Only then does it activate its rockets.

As for the retroreflectors - my logic was thus: space is cold, but sun is not. An object covered with vantablack would be at first invisible, but it'd heat up from the sun like crazy. Eventually it'd just start to glow on its own - not good. And also hard for the payload. Retroreflectors don't have this problem - they reflect most energy away. BUT - they direct it right back at the source. So the light from the sun will not make it into a bright dot - unless you're looking at it from exactly the right angle (you have to be between the sun and the thing)

@Ash - Ok, that's fair.

@Ash - whut? They're bog standard. Just take a look at any car/bicycle/roadsign

@Vilx- Sorry I was not thinking of the technology you were referring to, people using the name of a real technology for their sci-fi contraptions need to be slapped. I'm not sure that would help with stealth though it might be useful for preserving a comet from solar radiation.

@Ash I'm relying on the "space is big" thing. There's no real stealth, so you just got to blend in.

@Vilx- Reflecting sunlight makes you stick out in interplanetary space, out in interstellar space where light point sources are far more distant it might help you blend though.

@Ash - That's why retroreflectors. I want to reflect away all the light from the sun (so it doesn't heat the drone up), but I also don't want the object to be a bright white dot. Retroreflectors reflect the light back to the sun in a narrow cone. To see the drone you'd have to stand inside this cone with the sun behind your back. From all other angles it'd be as dark as the space surrounding it. Plus, since it is, you know, small (I imagine it the size of a car or less), it'd become reeeeally tiny really fast. Even a few thousand kilometers away it'd already appear minuscule.

This answer also seems to be a why should the stone be shot into space answer: it's hard to find small things in space, especially if they're not advertising themselves, and are moving away.

Because the stone upon which the hive mind's True Name is inscribed must be present in order to add a new member to the hive mind.  Members of the hive mind may give birth and die, but for the children of the members to also become members requires that they read the stone.
Shoot the stone into space or just bury it somewhere that no-one can find it, and it can't do its job of allowing the hive-mind to expand.  As members of the hive-mind die, the hive mind will shrink, losing its capabilities, without any way of restoring itself.
Obviously, such a stone would be kept under guard somewhere, covered so that it could not be read accidentally, but for it to serve its purpose, it has to be able to be read.  If it is defaced, it is a matter of urgency to repair or replace it.  It is the heart of the hive-mind, without which the hive-mind will - over a human lifetime, which to the hive-mind is a very short time - cease to exist.
Given that if a True Name stone is read by a member of another hive-mind, that other hive-mind can assimilate the hive-mind whose True Name has been read, this would, as the OP has said, put a premium upon preventing members of other hive-minds from gaining access to the stone.  Since the OP hasn't said if members of one hive-mind can tell if any given human unfamiliar to the hive-mind is a member of another hive-mind or just a normal human, I'd have to assume that the hive-mind can't tell.
In the event that a normal human/member of another hive-mind approaches a True Name stone, the members of the hive-mind would obviously have an interest in preventing that, up to and including the destruction of the True Name stone... but why would a hive-mind allow that, given how precious a True Name stone is?
That's because secrecy trumps expansion.  Reveal the secret of the hive's True Name to another hive, and the hive potentially ends, assimilated by the other hive.  Lose a True Name stone, and the hive can't grow... but it can create a new stone, in a period of time much shorter than a human life.  Obviously, this new stone would be created in a new secret location, but as long as it can continue doing its job of allowing the hive to expand, that's acceptable.

Because space is yes vast, but also open to anyone.
While on any place on the planet you can guard it and reinforce it when needed, once thrown into space the name will be naked and available for anybody to read it, be it a dumb slug or an alien hivemind.
Additionally, since

When another hivemind reads the written true name, the hivemind whose true name has been discovered risks mental assimilation from the reader

if the name is read in space, it will take time for the effect to propagate, time which can be precious for avoiding assimilation.

+1 - smaller asteroids than 13x13x11 can be tracked by Earthbound systems quite easily, and it would be quite obvious if in the course of computing a new asteroid’s trajectory it would seem as though it originated from the planet whence the tracking takes place… an enemy could easily just launch a massive kinetic kill vehicle to intercept it at high speed and (since it has no reaction engines with which to dodge) that would be that for the hivemind.

The time factor is almost an argument for sending the stone into space...

Encryption.

The medium holding the true name must always convey the information to the universe with completeness, clarity and legibility

...to who? The universe speaks a lot of languages. But there are even more than it doesn't speak. What language are you writing this in that the whole universe speaks it?
More to the point, why not create a language that you can speak to the universe that can convey the information in an encrypted form? It will be complete, clear, and legible but also indecipherable to anyone not in the hive mind.
After all, if I say "correct horse battery staple" that is complete, clear, and legible. But if you don't share a certain experience with me you have no idea what I mean.

How does the "link" between the Stone and the minds of the hivemind work?
The problem is, if ANY kind of information is sent between the stone and the Minds, then sending it to space will either cause lag (because the stone is to far too communicate in real-time), or NOT cause lag despite the distance, which would violate causality. If your stone is a lightyear away, and yet the link between a member of the Hive and the stone is instantaneous, then the information acheived FTL speeds and time-travelled.
its up to you to decide whether FTL and time travel are impossible in your story, or possible but would destroy reality.


How do I justify this not working?

Simple, they haven't done it yet.
There are many things to be concerned about. It could simply be that the hive mind hasn't yet made up it's mind about this.
They may even have put together a space program with the idea of some day doing this. But have yet to demonstrate the capabilities that would give them the confidence to put all their eggs in this one basket.
You fight bad ideas with better ideas. All of this is academic if the hive feels they have a better way to hide the name. They must have one now since they still exist. Why fix what aint broke?
Not every member of the hive has to feel that way. This may be an issue that forces the hive to spend time in internal debate. Debate that keeps them from getting it done.
Space isn't easy. Neither is consensus.

How close do members of a hive mind have to be to each other before the mind breaks apart? It could be that Hive A launches a stone, if it gets away from Earth fast enough, when Hive B sends individuals out to read that stone, B fractures from time delay in keeping the hive synced. In other words, no hive can read A’s block without sending the whole hive out to read the block.

There must be only one
Having multiple copies of the true name would dilute it, perhaps causing a fracture in the collectiveness of the hivemind.
That is also the reason why it must be carved on a physical object instead of stored digitally, as any digital processing inherently involves making temporary copies.
A special ritual ensures smooth transfer when the block needs to be replaced, and involves destroying the old block. This wouldn't be possible if the old block was unreachable in space.
